# View and aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a list in the code behind page pages.aspx.cs. How to send this list to the view i.e., profile.cshtml? I'm using web forms and MVC together. I have a list in .aspx, how do I pass it to a controller so that I can use that list in the view.?
This is the list in pages.aspx.cs

List sites = new List();

```
        if (Guid.TryParse(SiteID.SelectedValue, out siteId))
        {
            sites = ServiceFactory<IOrganizationService>
                .Return( ( svc, ctx ) => svc.SitesForPostalCode( ctx, PostalCode.Text ) )
                .Where(s => s.Guid == siteId).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Are you mixing up web forms and MVC?  The way you get data to a view is through your controller.

Comment: @JackMarchetti yes! any sugegstions how to access that?

Comment: I got the solution for this:

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't use session or cookie? And why didn't you call this method in controller or view? Are you manipulating list in aspx page?

Comment: ozkan I want to manipulate the list in the view actually. I'm not able to figure out how to access this list in view from the code behind page of .aspx. I tried using this HttpContext.Current.Items["listkendo"] = sites; is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this:
In .aspx:
Session["toList"]=sites

In the controller:
 var locationList = (List)Session["toList"];